# Fourier transform of the 1-dimension heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

For the one dimentional heat equation $u_t=u_{xx}$, the book i am reading takes fourier transform on both sides of the equation with respect to x. My question is the following.

1: Is the fourier transform of $u_{xx}$ equal to the second derivative of U, the fourier transform of u? i i.e. is it true that $F(u_{xx}) = F(u)_{xx}$ (F is fourier operator)? If not, which is the right approach in this case?

2: why is the right-hand-side, after taking the fourier transform, equal to $-4\pi^2f^2U(f, t)$?

Comment: Look up the relation between Fourier transforms and derivatives.

Comment: ${\cal F}(f'')=-w^2{\cal F}(f)$

Comment: The more delicate problem is showing that $\mathcal{F}(u_t)=(\mathcal{F}(u))_t$.

Comment: @MyGlasses can you elaborate on why?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts yes i thought about that. Not sure why though. Please drop some hints.

Comment: As I wrote $F(u_{xx}) = -w^2F(u)=-4\pi^2f^2 F(u)$. This rule obtain from the definition of fourier transform. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Differentiation

Comment: @MyGlasses  aha i see what is going on. The typo on my book got the derivatives wrong. Can you comment on the first question as well? appreciate it.

Comment: Because there must be a convergence for all $x$ as $h\downarrow$ in $\frac{1}{h}(u(x,t+h)-u(x,t)$. That's because the the difference quotient is being integrated in $x$. So that's a tricky problem just to formulate, and generally gets into vector convergence in $L^2$, $L^1$, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are assumptions that must be placed on $u$ to even make sense of the Fourier transform. For the heat equation, it makes the most sense to assume $u$ is absolutely integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ in order for the total heat to be finite. However, you could instead assume $u$ is square integrable, even though this is not necessarily physical for the heat equation. If you assume $u$ is locally absolutely continuous in $x$, with locally absolutely continuous $u_x$, and if you assume $u,u_x,u_{xx}$ are absolutely square integrable, then the integration by parts evaluation terms vanish and you get what you want. For example,
$$
      (\mathcal{F}u_{x})(s,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u_x(x,t)e^{-isx}dx \\
  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}u(x,t)e^{-isx}|_{x=-\infty}^{\infty}+\frac{is}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(x,t)e^{-isx}dx \\
  = (is\mathcal{F}u)(s,t).
$$
Either set of assumptions mentioned above will allow you to conclude that the integration-by-parts evaluation terms vanish, leaving
$$
                \mathcal{F}u_x = is\mathcal{F}u \\
         \mathcal{F}u_{xx} = is\mathcal{F}u_x = -s^2\mathcal{F}u.
$$
However, what is not obvious is an assumption that will allow an interchange of the time derivative with the Fourier integral
$$
            (\mathcal{F}u_t) = (\mathcal{F}u)_t,
$$
which is to say
$$
     \lim_{h\downarrow 0}\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{u(\cdot,t+h)-u(\cdot,t)}{h}\right)=\mathcal{F}(u_t).
$$
A typical assumption is that the difference quotient converges as $h\downarrow 0$ to $u_t$ either in $L^1$ or in $L^2$. If this holds, then
$$
          (\mathcal{F}u)_t = -s^2\mathcal{F}u \\
      \implies (\mathcal{F}u)(s,t) = (\mathcal{F}u)|_{t=0}e^{-s^2t}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the fourier transform is used in PDE is that it has very nice properties with respect to differentiation.

Let $\mathcal{F} (f) $ denote the Fourier transform of $f$ then you can easily get the Fourier transform of $f'$ from it:

$$ \mathcal{F}(f') (\xi) = 2 \pi i \xi \mathcal{F} (f) (\xi) $$

Apply this again to obtain the Fourier  transform of the second derivative
$$ \mathcal{F}(f'') (\xi) = (2 \pi i \xi )^{2} \mathcal{F}(f)(\xi) $$
This is for a real function $f$, in your case you have a function of two variables $(t,x)$. 
Now, try to compute the Fourier transform of $u$. 
$$ \mathcal{F}(u) (\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}} u(t,x)e^{-2 \pi i(t \omega_1 + x \omega_2 )} dx dt $$ 
where of course $ \omega = (\omega_1,\omega_2) $.

Now you can return to your problem, you can explicitly compute the Fourier transform of $ u_t $ and $ u_{xx} $. (Hint: Separate the integral into $2$ integrate one first....) 
Can you finish from here?